# Android weight property error in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have 5 horizontal linear layout is there. I aligned three edittext in a single linear layout. And I applied the weight field property 1 for all the editext. But in 1st and 3rd linear layout working perfectly with the property. Others are not working properly. Again in 5th horizontal linear layout have one spinner view, it was also creating the same problem. Then 4th line one addition linear layout available inside the horizontal layout, with one edittext and one imageview. It is also not fixing properly with weight property. I put layout code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/yellow" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sign_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Sign Up" />
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/f_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" >
        </EditText>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/l_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="Last Name"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/uname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Username *"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    <LinearLayout//this layout creating alignment issue. if I put extra space in hint nearly it was getting good view. But different screens wont work
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="Phone"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/plan_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="Member Plan ID"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password *"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="50"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="Address"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="Mobile *     "
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email *   "
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="City"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="State"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">//tried this not worked 
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dob"
                android:layout_width="265dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:textSize="18dp"        
                android:inputType="date"
                android:hint="Date of Birth"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/img_dob"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cal" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<Space 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Country"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zipcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Zipcode  "
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_yellow_singleline" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_width="305dp"//finally hard coded but it wont work for multiple screens
        android:layout_height="40dp"
         />

</LinearLayout>
<Space 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Done"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button_shape" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

If it won't work means, will the table layout give solution for this?

If I reduce the text inside the hint then also it was working fine in 2nd line. If I provide space for keeping same text length in with other edittext field which contains low text also not worked.

Comment: Add a weightsum for all the horizantal linearlayouts

Comment: can you add some screenshot + another image with what you expect to get?

Comment: Thank you Hari, Gavriel. Droid's answer fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your EditText should have:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

And all LinearLayout should have:

```
android:weightsum="3"
```